# Is there a way to upload files to Azure file share using apache nifi?

Tags: azure, apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

I am trying to upload files to Azure file share present in azure storage account. Is there any combination of processors in nifi that I can use to upload files. Unfortunately there is no direct processor for file share available like blob storage.

Comment: Possible to use executegroovyscript with quite simple java code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell or executeprocess with az command line https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_upload

Comment: Are you referring to NFS?